# Where is a good resource for switching to PHP from Ruby on Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I have run an application in Rails for 6 years. We are getting ready to design a new version from the ground up. This is a *very* data intensive application, and there are always lots and lots of operations going on in the background. There are two issues I have with Ruby on Rails:

1) I don't think the performance is quite what it could be.

2) There seems to be such a major effort to abstract the database to AREL. I like AREL, but we are always going to use MySQL. This application will never point at another data source. Therefore, writing SQL will be much simpler, and will allow much more flexibility.

There are several things that I do like about Rails, and I will continue to use it for other applications that I have. I love the separation of concerns. I think the best part of Rails is the awesome community and all the gems that allow me to stand on the shoulders of people smarter than me.

I am looking for a resource that can tell me about switching to PHP from Rails. Among the initial questions I have are:

1) Is there a PHP framework that provides an MVC separation of concerns similar to Rails?

2) Is there anything analogous to gems or plugins?

Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Comment: You should consider other solutions... FastCgi based, or OPA http://opalang.org/

Comment: 1) There are a lot of articles going with / against that, so I'd say it's definitely debatable.  

2) Not really sure what you mean, but Rails is extremely good about handling multiple DB structures so you're not limited to one or the other, as you may have noticed.

-----

1) You may want to check out [CodeIgniter][1] for PHP.  Many say that it was based off of Rails.

2)  CodeIgniter comes with [Sparks][2], which is basically the PHP equivelant to Ruby Gems.


  [1]: http://codeigniter.com/
  [2]: http://getsparks.org/

Comment: This is addressed to the people that closed my question: Come on everybody, I think you might be taking yourselves a little bit too seriously. "We expect answers to generally involve ... specific expertise." That's what the question was designed to elicit. not a flame war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at CakePHP

http://cakephp.org/